# Function to get a value from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php function:

```
function getCredEstud(int $ciEstud) {
   include_once 'conexion.php';
   $result = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT DISTINCT `creditosEstudiante` FROM `op_JOIN_est-insc-mat` WHERE ciEstudiante = '".$ciEstud."'");
   $i=0;
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       return (int)$row["creditosEstudiante"];
       $i++;
   }
   mysqli_close($conexion);
}
```

which should get the value of "creditosEstudiantes" from a given "ciEstudiante" of the below table.

The problem is that it return nothing.

Could someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance! =)

```
randomNum   ciEstudiante    creditosEstudiante  codigoMateria   tipoMateria cupoMateria creditosMateria     
0   1780859     75  1035    CURRICULAR  0   3
0   1780859     75  1954    OPTATIVA    25  0
0   1780859     75  1025    CURRICULAR  0   3
0   1780859     75  1910    OPTATIVA    LIBRE   0
0   1780859     75  1948    OPTATIVA    60  0
0   1780859     75  2105P   CURRICULAR  0   4
0   1780859     75  2100P   CURRICULAR  0   4
0   1780859     75  2095    CURRICULAR  0   3
0   1780859     75  4170    CURRICULAR  0   3
0   1780859     75  1932    OPTATIVA    30  0
0   1780859     75  3140    CURRICULAR  0   4
0   1780859     75  2190    CURRICULAR  0   4
0   1780859     75  2115P   CURRICULAR  0   4
0   1921177     93  2115P   CURRICULAR  0   4
0   1921177     93  2095    CURRICULAR  0   3
0   1921177     93  2105P   CURRICULAR  0   4
0   1921177     93  2100P   CURRICULAR  0   4
0   2020703     269     3140    CURRICULAR  0   4
0   2020703     269     4160    CURRICULAR  0   3
0   2762533     249     3020P   CURRICULAR  0   28
0   2971526     355     1954    OPTATIVA    25  0
0   3102055     55  1021    CURRICULAR  0   25
0   3102055     55  2095    CURRICULAR  0   3
```

Here is the full code:

```
    <?php

function getRandomCIEstud() {
   include_once 'conexion.php';
   $result = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT DISTINCT `ciEstudiante` FROM `op_JOIN_est-insc-mat` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
   $i=0;
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       //$selectedCI=$row["ciEstudiante"];
       return $RandomCIEstud=$row["ciEstudiante"];
       //echo $RandomCIEstud=(int)$row["ciEstudiante"];
       $i++;
   }
   mysqli_close($conexion);
}


function getCredEstud(int $ciEstud) {
   include_once 'conexion.php';
   $where = 'WHERE `ciEstudiante` = ?';
    if (empty($ciEstud)) {
        $ciEstud = 0;
        $where = 'ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';
    }
   $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `creditosEstudiante` FROM `op_JOIN_est-insc-mat` ".$where;  
   //result is boolean for query other than SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE and EXPLAIN
   if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql)) {

       // bind parameters for markers
       if ($ciEstud <> 0) {
            //mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $ciEstud);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $ciEstud);
       }

      // execute query
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

     // bind result variables
     mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $result);

     // fetch values
     $i=0;
     while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        return (int)$result;
        $i++;
     }
    if ($i==0) {
        // if no entry is found return -1
        return -1;
    }
    // close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
 } else {
      printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
 }
 mysqli_close($conexion);
}   


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Retrive data</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
<td>getRandomCIEstud(): <?php $randomCI=getRandomCIEstud(); echo $randomCI; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
<td>getCredEstud(): <?php echo getCredEstud((int)$randomCI); ?></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the code I have so far. I tried everithing but it doesnt work right now. It doesnt show any error, it just dont return anything. I guess It is something wrong with the way I am passing the parameters.

Thank you all very much for your help

Comment: Couple of points: including mathematical operators in table names is a cataclysmically bad idea, and see about sql injection

Comment: While technically this piece of code is not vulnerable to SQL injection, it shows that you have no idea how to include PHP variable in SQL. I recommend you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement before proceeding with anything else.

Comment: Do not add nonsense to your question to avoid the system which is put in place. Instead add a more detailed description of what you want to do. Please read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `op_JOIN_est-insc-mat` (
>   `randomNum` INTEGER,
>   `ciEstudiante` INTEGER,
>   `creditosEstudiante` INTEGER,
>   `codigoMateria` VARCHAR(5),
>   `tipoMateria cupoMateria creditosMateria` VARCHAR(10)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `op_JOIN_est-insc-mat` 
>   (`randomNum`, `ciEstudiante`, `creditosEstudiante`, `codigoMateria`
>   , `tipoMateria cupoMateria creditosMateria`)
> VALUES
>   ('0', '1780859', '75', '1035', 'CURRICULAR'),
>   ('0', '1780859', '75', '1954', 'OPTATIVA'),
>   ('0', '1780859', '75', '1025', 'CURRICULAR'),
>   ('0', '1780859', '75', '1910', 'OPTATIVA'),
>   ('0', '1780859', '75', '1948', 'OPTATIVA'),
>   ('0', '1780859', '75', '2105P', 'CURRICULAR'),
>   ('0', '1780859', '75', '2100P', 'CURRICULAR'),
>   ('0', '1780859', '75', '2095', 'CURRICULAR'),
>   ('0', '1780859', '75', '4170', 'CURRICULAR'),
>   ('0', '1780859', '75', '1932', 'OPTATIVA'),
>   ('0', '1780859', '75', '3140', 'CURRICULAR'),
>   ('0', '1780859', '75', '2190', 'CURRICULAR'),
>   ('0', '1780859', '75', '2115P', 'CURRICULAR'),
>   ('0', '1921177', '93', '2115P', 'CURRICULAR'),
>   ('0', '1921177', '93', '2095', 'CURRICULAR'),
>   ('0', '1921177', '93', '2105P', 'CURRICULAR'),
>   ('0', '1921177', '93', '2100P', 'CURRICULAR'),
>   ('0', '2020703', '269', '3140', 'CURRICULAR'),
>   ('0', '2020703', '269', '4160', 'CURRICULAR'),
>   ('0', '2762533', '249', '3020P', 'CURRICULAR'),
>   ('0', '2971526', '355', '1954', 'OPTATIVA'),
>   ('0', '3102055', '55', '1021', 'CURRICULAR'),
>   ('0', '3102055', '55', '2095', 'CURRICULAR');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT `ciEstudiante` INTO @id FROM `op_JOIN_est-insc-mat` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT `creditosEstudiante` 
> FROM `op_JOIN_est-insc-mat`
> WHERE `ciEstudiante` = @id
> ```
>
> ```
> | creditosEstudiante |
> | -----------------: |
> |                269 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=32e4efe0722d68a632c691f2b5f86b5f)*

But your code is **vulnerable to sql injection** so use only **prepared statements with parameters**

As you can see i rewrote your code, but it looks like you don't expect more than one result (because of the return ) from your query as shown in the Select example abouve, but still you use a while loop and don't limit the result to 1

So you want to check that

```
 function getCredEstud(int $ciEstud) {
   include_once 'conexion.php';
   $where = 'WHERE `ciEstudiante` = ?';
    if (empty($ciEstud)) {
        $ciEstud = 0;
        $where = 'ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';
    }
   $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `creditosEstudiante` FROM `op_JOIN_est-insc-mat` ".$where;  
   //result is boolean for query other than SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE and EXPLAIN
   if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql)) {

       /* bind parameters for markers */
       if ($ciEstud <> 0) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $ciEstud);
       }

      /* execute query */
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

     /* bind result variables */
     mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $result);

     /* fetch values */
     $i=0;
     while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        return (int)$result;
        $i++;
     }
    if ($i==0) {
        /* if no entry is found return -1  */
        return -1;
    }
    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
 } else {
      printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
 }
 mysqli_close($conexion);
}
```

**Change** Your query to

```
SELECT `creditosEstudiante` FROM `op_JOIN_est-insc-mat` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Which will a random creditosEstudiante, if that is what you want

Your logic is off

```
 `<td>getRandomCIEstud(): <?php $myid = getRandomCIEstud(); echo $myid;?></td> 
 <td>getCredEstud(): <?php echo getCredEstud((int)$myid); ?></td>`
```

As you see you have to save the id you get to run it throw your function else it will give you different random number

Comment: It doesn't bring any data (but it should bring data). It doesn't show any error either, it works like the function I wrote...

Comment: You  didn't show,how you call then function, so check the value of $ciEstud if i shpuld gues it is empty

Comment: I post the full code. I guess the same as you. But I test it and it seems to works fine... Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: i add to my question this `getCredEstud((int)getRandomCIEstud())`can't reurn anything because your function expects a ciEstudiante any but you don't delivers any so th the routione search for ciEstudiante = 0 which has no result. In your case use my query at the end of my answer

Comment: As I see you "join" both functions into one. I guess it will work but I need to make it work the way I wrote it. That is, to find a random CI (student document number) from the table. For that I wrote the "getRandomCIEstud" function. That one works. So no problem there.
Then I need to pass that number I found (the random CI) to the other function (getCredEstud) in order to get the number of credits for that random student.
So I really needs that works that way: one function find the random ci (getRandomCIEstud) and pass that number to the other function (getCredEstud).
Thank you.

Comment: i chnged the function, this will give you a creditosEstudiante for a specific $ciEstud , if you don't give3 onbe as in your code it picks a random. I think from here you can solve your problem

Comment: Im sorry but it is not working. The output I get is this:        

getRandomCIEstud(): 4791506        
getCredEstud(): Error: .           

I calling the functions like this:

<td>getRandomCIEstud(): <?php echo getRandomCIEstud(); ?></td>
and
<td>getCredEstud(): <?php echo getCredEstud((int)getRandomCIEstud()); ?></td>

Thank you

Comment: Error logging is enable and it doesnt show any error...

Comment: I see what you mean and you are right. but that did not make the diference because it wont gave a wrong number, it dont return anything, I pasted the right now code with all the changes we made and if you run it you will see the problem...

Comment: sorry i don't see it, what i did in the changed dbfidle is that whqat we, do in the code. so you shoud have in the first echo a number and the second should also give a number as you can see in teh dbfiddle. When not add a many echo as you need to debug your code especially if the second function gets a number and uses it